# java stream Collectors without mapper?

Tags: java, stream, summarize

I want to call `Collectors.summarizingInt` on a set with Integers. Examples I have seen so far are on a Set with (say) Employees and are then called as `collect(Collecters.summorizingInt(Employee::getWage))`. For the bare Integers summorizingInt needs an argument so I can do `collect(Collectors.summarizingInt((i) -> i))` but it feels a bit strange to provide a self mapper.

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option could be combining [mapToInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) to convert it to the `IntStream` and then call [summaryStatistics()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics()) on it:

```java
 IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = Set.of(1, 3, 4)
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .summaryStatistics();
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
Set<Integer> integers;
integers.stream().collect(
  Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));
```